# How do you find the area of a Venn diagram?

Tags: geometry, area

If we have a Venn diagram (only two circles)

[image]

And the larger circles have a radius of 2...

If the middle circle has a radius of 1, how can we find the area of the intersection part?

I understand that side is the middle of the larger circles, but I'm still confused on what to do to find the area of the middle intersection part.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: As currently phrased, the question confuses me.  A Venn diagram is a way of describing the ways in which sets intersect---Venn diagrams are set theoretic objects.  "Area", on the other hand, requires some notion of measure or geometry.  We can make sense of the area of intersection of two Venn diagrams by assuming that the sets described live in some probability space, but such a space needs to be described.  On the other hand, maybe you mean to ask "What is the area where two disks intersect?"  If so, your question is still unclear, as the relations between the circles are unclear.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to compute twice the area of the circular segment delimited by the line connecting the two intersection points: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment

What you were drawing in red is a bit confusing (the line you drew to indicate the "radius" of the big circles doesn't seem to pass through their centre, as it should be given the numbers you were posting). However if the two large circles have a **radius** equal to 2, and the **radius** of the inner circle tangent to the two bigger ones is equal to 1, then the distance between the centres of the big circles will be $d_c = 2R - 2r = 2$, i.e. each big circle pass through the centre of the other one. Thus, the distance between each centre and the line connecting the intersection points is $d = d_c/2 = 1$. Now, following the formula for the area of the circular segment, the whole area of the intersection is $$A = 2R\biggl(R\arccos(d/R)-d\,\sqrt{1-(d/R)^2} \biggr) = 4\biggl(\frac{2\pi}{3} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\biggr) = \frac{8\pi-6\sqrt{3}}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

[image: Figure]

$\triangle CAB$ is equilateral, i.e. $\text{ar}\triangle CAB=\frac{\sqrt3}4(2)^2=\sqrt3$. Area of **sector** $CAB$ is $\frac{60}{360}\pi(2)^2=2\pi/3$.

Thus the area of the shaded region is $2\pi/3-\sqrt3$ and the area of the top-half of the intersection region is the sum of the areas of sector $CAB$ and the shaded region, i.e. $4\pi/3-\sqrt3$, giving the required area as its double $8\pi/3-2\sqrt3$.

Answer (score 0):

Note the centre of each circle is on the other circle. The area of the intersection is the area of the circular sector $AIB$ minus the area of triangle $AIB$.[image]

Elementary trigonometry shows that angle $\widehat{AIH} $ is equal to $\frac{\pi}3$,  so the length $AH$ is $2\sin\frac\pi 3=\sqrt 3$ and the area of triangle $AIB$ is twice the area of triangle $AIH$, i.e. also $\color{red}{\sqrt{3}}$.

On the other hand, as angle $\widehat{AIB}=\frac{2\pi} 3$ by symmetry, the area of the circular sector $AIB$ is equal to $\frac12\cdot 4\cdot\frac{2\pi}3=\color{red}{\frac{4\pi}3}$.

Ultimately, the area of the intersection is twice the difference, i.e.
$$\frac{8\pi}3-2\sqrt 3.$$