# Calculate distance between centers of circles given area of intersections

Tags: trigonometry, circles, area

I'm working on a representation of multiple regression effect sizes using a Venn Diagram for educational policy research. I understand there are ways to calculate the area of the sectors given the distance between centers ([for example at this link here](https://www.benfrederickson.com/calculating-the-intersection-of-3-or-more-circles/#:%7E:text=Its%20an%20exceedingly%20simple%20approach%3A%20just%20randomly%20sample,multiplied%20by%20the%20size%20of%20the%20bounding%20rectangle.)), so there should be a way to find the distance between centers given the area. I thought answers to [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4007172/how-do-you-find-the-area-of-a-venn-diagram) would help, but I'm having trouble following the procedure. I have very little calculus and trigonometry background, so a step-by-step procedure would help a lot.

**Given**: three circles have centers X, Y, and Z with radii of sqrt(1/pi). The area of the sectors are given in the diagram, at [this link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyK4N.png).

**Question**: what is the length of the lines connecting the centers of the circles?

---

**Update**: After doing more digging, I think this is about [areas of geometric lenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_(geometry)). Since $$A_{lens}=r^2cos^{-1}(\frac{d^2+r^2-R^2}{2dr})+R^2cos^{-1}(\frac{d^2+R^2-r^2}{2dr})-2\Delta$$
where
$$\Delta=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(-d+r+R)(d-r+R)(d+r-R)(d+r+R)}$$
and
$$r=R=\sqrt{1/\pi}$$
and, for example,
$$A_{A\cap B}=0.23$$
therefore (per [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=2%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2C%CF%80%5D%5C%2840%29ArcCos%5BDivide%5BPower%5Bz%2C2%5D%2C2zSqrt%5BDivide%5B1%2C%CF%80%5D%5D%5D%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29-%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2C2%5DSqrt%5B%5C%2840%29-z%2B2Sqrt%5BDivide%5B1%2C%CF%80%5D%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29z%2B2Sqrt%5BDivide%5B1%2C%CF%80%5D%5D%5C%2841%29%5D%5C%2841%29%3D0.23)),
$$d\approx 0.429$$

Could someone validate this for me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do the centers form an equilateral triangle ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I think that is unlikely.

Comment: In this case, knowing only the common area $D_1 \cap D_2 \cap D_3$ is not enough to recover the centers' positions : you will have an infinite set of solutions.

Comment: @JeanMarie Fascinating. Thank you. If you don't mind, what is/are the missing variable/s?

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your last comment (see figure below).

For a fixed distance $d$ between centers $X$ and $Y$, there is an infinite number of positions of point $Z$ giving the same value for the common area of the 3 disks ; the different positions of $Z$ are  - very approximately - given by the (red) parabola-like curve.

Therefore, in order to answer your question about the "missing variables" that I would call the (number of) degrees of freedom of this issue, I answer by saying there are two of them :

- distance $d = XY$
- position of $Z$ on its curve.

(there is a "natural" degree of freedom we have not to take into account which allows to rotate the figure).

[image]

Comment: please see my update

Comment: No comment about what I have done : understanding this issue by keeping 2 circles fixed and moving the center of the third circle in order to preserve the area of the intersection of the 3 disks ?

Comment: I think finding position of z has a closed form solution, given distance of XZ, XY, and YZ